Запретить [google]
Вступление
Не так давно были выпилены метки google (~600 вопросов) с её фактическим синонимом google-api (~200 вопросов).
Почему данные метки не должны существовать и должны быть запрещены

У компании Гугл очень много сервисов и API, метка неоднозначна и не может быть полезна. По этой же причине на enSO сожгли её сожгли, а у нас google запланировали сжечь много лет назад.

Вместо конкретных меток (например google-chrome, google-maps, google-drive и так далее) вешают google. Из-за этого затрудняется поиск, а это для меток задача №1. Можно сделать вывод, что метка не просто бесполезна, а ещё и несёт вред.

Так как вопросов с ней было не так уж и мало, и высока вероятность, что её создадут снова, её стоит запретить (внести в чёрный список).


Всплывающая подсказка о запрете
Если метка запрещается, то у неё высвечивается подсказка, почему она была запрещена. Сначала просто факт запрета, он для всех меток един:

Метка [название-метки] запрещена.

А потом уже конкретное предупреждение для конкретной метки. Для нашего случая я предлагаю такое:

У компании Google много различных сервисов, поэтому выбирайте более конкретные метки: [google-chrome], [google-spreadsheet], [google-drive], [google-account] и так далее.

На что я ещё хотел бы обратить внимание
Запретить надо и google, и google-api.

В предупреждении, может быть, лучше будет поэтому стоит выбирать -> выбирайте?

@wchistow пожалуй, да, ведь "стоит выбирать" != "выбирайте". Исправил. Жаль, что раньше не заметили, у метки [tag:яндекс] повесили "стоит выбирать".

We have blocked both the google and google-api and added the suggested tag block guidance text as well.

Мы запретили google и google-api и добавили предложенный текст предупреждения.
